# Visual Studio 2019 installation caused Type '' is not defined errors (.NET Framework 4 project)

Tags: .net, vb.net

I was using Visual Studio 2015. I installed VS 2019. Since then, my desktop application that targets Framework 4 won't compile. I get hundreds of "Type '' is not defined errors". This is nonsense and there is no problem with references. If I select Framework 4.5 it compiles ! But I'd like to keep it at Framework 4.

Even in 2015, I can't compile it. Any ideas?

I've already tried deleting .vs folder. No joy

Comment: Does a Clean help?  Also, check the platform... sometimes I have troubles if I don't use x86.

Comment: Have you perhaps inadvertently uninstalled the v4 framework?

Comment: I tried that but Framework 4 is definately there, such a strange problem